# Integrate fractional part function 2

Tags: integration

I have to find the values of $x \in \mathbb R$ so that

$$\int _0^1\frac{dt}{1+\left\{x+t\right\}}\:=\:\ln2$$

To be noted that the answer is $\mathbb R$.

$$\int _0^1\:\frac{dt}{1+\left\{x+t\right\}}\:=\int _0^1\:\frac{dt}{1+x+t-\left[x+t\right]}=\int _0^1\:\frac{dt}{1+x+t-x}=\ln2$$

I solved it like this, but I don't really know, couldn't $[x+t]$ be also $x+1$ ?

Comment: Observe that $\{x\}\in (-1,1)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Then you can divide the integrals in parts where $\{x\}=t$ for $t\in(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By a substitution $x+t=u$, $dt = du$, we have
$$
\int_0^1 \frac1{1+\{x+t\}}dt = \int_x^{x+1} \frac1{1+\{u\}}du.
$$
This integral is in fact independent of $x$, so we have
$$
\int_x^{x+1} \frac1{1+\{u\}}du = \int_0^1 \frac1{1+\{u\}}du = \int_0^1 \frac 1{1+u}du = \ln (1+u) \bigg\vert_0^1 = \ln 2. 
$$

Comment: Why is it independent of x ?

Comment: Try splitting the integral into $\int_x^{\lfloor x \rfloor +1} $ and $\int_{\lfloor x \rfloor +1}^{x+1}$.

Comment: @i707107 Nice change of variables and translation !  If you've time, call me to upvote you tmr since my daily vote limit reached.